# Why vscode display all properties from my prisma model instead of the model name when I hover it?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, prisma

I don't get why when I write a function that use prisma and return a Promise like this :

```
import { Prisma, User } from "@prisma/client";

export const getUserByEmail = async ({
  email,
}: GetUserByEmailParams): Promise<User> => {
  const user = await db.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      email: email,
    },
  });

  return user;
};
```

would show me the full entity displayed when I hover the variable (I use vscode) :

[image: screenshot]

but any other function, for example this one :

```
interface randomFunc {
  test: string;
}
export const randomFunction = async (): Promise<randomFunc> => {
  return Promise.resolve({ test: "test" });
};
```

would show me this when I hover the variable :

[[image: screenshot2]

I have no idea if it's related to prisma or vscode config ?

When I hover a variable that is a Promise of one of my prisma model, that would be better to me to get "Promise" but I don't know why I can't get this.